# The following code needs manipulations with the same number of code lines

Tags: c

The following code is used to find the average of the marks of students of a class, but unfortunately, the code shows 2nd as 2th and 3rd as 3th too, so I've been struggling to get the code right with the same number of code lines

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int marks[10],sum=0,i;
float avg;

for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
printf("Enter the next element to be inserted into the array\n");
scanf("%d",&marks[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
sum = sum+marks[i];
printf("mark %dth=%d\nsum=%d\n",i,marks[i],sum);
}

avg = sum/10;

printf("The average of the 10 elements of the array is %f",avg);

}
```

How can we make the code print 2th as 2nd and 3th as 3rd while still keeping most of the code unchanged?

Comment: A simple `switch` or `if-else if` chain to add special cases for those?

Comment: `%d%s...",...,((j=(i%100))==1?"st":j==2?"nd":j==3?"rd":"th")` and assume `int j` declafred.

Comment: @Scheff,  nice idea. Done.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's a bit more complicated, because you write 11th but 21st/31st/etc. Though here it seems to only go up to 9 so that isn't a problem.

Comment: The "same number of code lines" does not even sound like one of those wanton restrictions for didactical purposes. What is the background?

Comment: Avoid the problem by rewriting the result (as "mark 2nd=5" doesn't even sound good to me). Make it "mark #2=5" and get over it.

Comment: Apparently, if `i` is `0`, the value is turned into the ordinal `0th`, although the text desribes the _first_ value. Is this desired?

Comment: lets hope we get an answer soon :(